# Why does sysout(upper class) invoke toString of lower class after assigning lower class to upper class?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, tostring, variable-assignment

I have two classes A and B while B is a subtype of A:

```
public class A {
    private String stringVar;

    public A()  {
        stringVar = "";
    }

    public String getStringVar() {
        return stringVar;
    }

    public void setStringVar(String str) {
        this.stringVar = str;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString()  {
        return getStringVar();
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends A {
    private int intVar;

    public B()  {
        intVar = 0;
    }

    public int getIntVar() {
        return intVar;
    }

    public void setIntVar(int intVar) {
        this.intVar = intVar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()  {
        return super.toString() + " " + getIntVar();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the following main method I assign the b to a. Now "a" can't invoke b's methods which is clear, because I'm using an instance of type A now. But it behaves like a B when toString is invoked. Curious, I would have expected toString of a. Why is this so?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        b.setIntVar(200);
        b.setStringVar("foo");
        a = b;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the fundamental concept of polymorphism. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nature of inheritance / polymorphism and overriding methods.

Overrided methods will be determined in runtime based on objects real type and not based on reference type.

Therefore a.toString() is actually b.toString() because it is determined in runtime.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 2):

Because a points to the implementation of B.
And is declared as A.

So behavior of B. And methods visible of A.

To use B methods do like this

```
((B) a).getIntVar();
```

Think of it like this

```
Object o = new FancyObject();
```

When compiling this only Objects methods will be accepted even though it's a FancyObjcet with lots of methods.

To use the methods of FancyObject on o do like this.

```
Object o = new FancyObject();
(FancyObject o).fancyMethod();
```

Quote *"because I'm using an instance of type A now"* you are still using an instance of type B. You can see it like you have upcasted b but it's the same instance.

Picture cross linked from another site with credits in the picture, if this is against the rules then somebody is free to edit this part of my answer. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The concept you need to understand is the difference between References and Objects.

`a` is a reference (a local variable in this case) that points first to an Object of type `A` and then to an Object of type `B`.

The compiler knows that it must be of type A (or a subtype thereof), so it can safely call all methods A defines, but they will be called on the actual Object, not on the original Type of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

That is called [runtime polymorphism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in OOP.

Comment: [OOPs is a term that nobody outside of India understands](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33299/whats-oops-is-that-term-in-use). Stick with OOP. Lose the s. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is polymorphism: The object that a holds has static type A, but it is still an Object of dynamic type B. Dynamic dispatch therefore chooses the overridden toString() defined in B.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how Java's runtime polymorphism works.  All that matters is the *actual* type at runtime.  What you have done is take a reference to an `A` and point it at an *instance* of `B`.  You have changed the type of the thing that `a` points to.

Try

`a = (A)b;`

Answer (score 0):

No, B Overrides the toString method of A, so if an object is an instance of B, when you call its toString method, you get whatever method that instance has. In general, if you have an object and call its methods, the method called is the one that is in the instance, not in the variable type. The only exception is static methods.

In C++, this is not the case. The method called is the one of the variable type, if one exists, unless you explicitly select the above described behavior by making a method virtual.